# Image centered on chrome and firefox, but not safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have an image I want to put in the center of my page.

Its centered on Firefox and Chrome using this code:

html:

```
<div id="logo">
<img src="images/logo.png" width="80%">
</div>
```

Css:

```
#logo{

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index:1;
    text-align:center;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    border-radius:50px;


}
```

But when I open the page on Safari, the image is to the right of the page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use browser prefixes:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform), Safari is still dependent on the `-webkit-` prefix.

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)
- [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)

(Also, since you're new, to accept an answer you click the green button.  This gives you and me reputation).